# How to properly trait object that works with object-unsafe types?

Tags: rust

I want to create a vector containing trait objects that have a `val` method that returns a comparable value:

```rust
trait Comparable {
    fn val(&self) -> Box<dyn std::cmp::Ord>;
}

struct Int64Array {}

impl Comparable for Int64Array {
    fn val(&self, i: usize) -> Box<dyn std::cmp::Ord> {
        Box::new(i+1)
    } 
}

struct StringArray {}

impl Comparable for StringArray {
    fn val(&self, i: usize) -> Box<dyn std::cmp::Ord> {
        Box::new(format!("foo_{}", i))
    }
}

fn main() {
    // each row is guaranteed to have vector elements with the same type 
    let rows: Vec<Box<dyn Comparable>> = vec![
        Box::new(Int64Array{}),
        Box::new(StringArray{}),
    ];
    println!("{}", rows[0].val(0).cmp(rows[0].val(1)));
    println!("{}", rows[1].val(0).cmp(rows[1].val(1)));
}
```

However, because `std::cmp::Ord` is not a object-safe trait, this won't compile. What's the recommend way to workaround this limitation?

Comment: `Ord` only works for comparing two objects with the same type, which is why this is failing. How are you expecting `1` to compare against `"foo".to_string()` anyway?

Comment: Even if you were able to create a trait object for `Ord`, you couldn't compare two `Box<dyn Ord>`, because they might be different types. You cannot compare a `StringType` with a `Int64Type`, that's not how the `Ord` trait works.

Comment: my bad, updated the sample code to account for type differences. I tried to simplify the sample code too much.

Comment: "each row is guaranteed to have vector elements with the same type" it might be easier to make each *row* a `dyn Something` (i.e. erase the type of the inner `Vec`, e.g. `Vec<Box<dyn Row>>`)

Comment: @FrancisGagné, updated sample code as you suggested.

Comment: With your current edit, you could instead have `arr[0].compare(0, 1)` and ditch `val`. The point is that you need to very explicitly operate on a single row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks everyone for the quick replies.

Combing suggestions from @FrancisGagné and @loganfsmyth, here is a workaround that avoids using Ord trait directly:

```rust
trait Comparable {
    fn compare(&self, i: usize, j: usize) -> std::cmp::Ordering;
}

struct Int64Array {}

impl Comparable for Int64Array {
    fn compare(&self, _i: usize, _j: usize) -> std::cmp::Ordering {
        std::cmp::Ordering::Equal
    } 
}

struct StringArray {}

impl Comparable for StringArray {
    fn compare(&self, _i: usize, _j: usize) -> std::cmp::Ordering {
        std::cmp::Ordering::Equal
    }
}

fn main() {
    // each row is guaranteed to have vector elements with the same type 
    let rows: Vec<Box<dyn Comparable>> = vec![
        Box::new(Int64Array{}),
        Box::new(StringArray{}),
    ];
    println!("{:#?}", rows[0].compare(0, 1));
    println!("{:#?}", rows[1].compare(0, 1));
}
```

I wonder if there is other ways to implement this feature.